# Dealing with a very big IF ELSE statement in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, if-statement, query-builder

I have a huge if else statement to handle my QuerBuilder i programmed in my page:

It looks something like:

```
if(dropdown == "something")
   {
         if(someotherdropdown == "something")
              {
               sqlStatement+ = some sql;
              }else
              {
               sqlStatement+ = some sql;
              }    
   }
   else if(dropdown == "something2")
   {
         sqlStatement+ = some sql;
   }
```

........... And it keeps going, to me it makes sense and also works fine
The thing is there another alternative? because it's so big now and more is about to come.
So I'm afraid it looks very amateur style.
I would like to have some advice.
Thanks allot

Comment: you can use switch statement in place of if else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This..

```
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case "something":
        sqlStatement+ = some sql;
        break;
    case "something1":
        sqlStatement+ = some sql;
        break;
    default:
        sqlStatement+ = some sql;
        break;
}
```